# How can I find the path to DLL generated by a different project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I have a VS solution that includes two projects (A and B) that generate DLLs, plus one project (C) that is dependent on those two DLLs at runtime.

I also have a project to test C and to make it work across all computer on my team I need to be able to find the path to the DLLs generated by A and B dynamically. How can I make this happen?

Comment: Just add C to the solution as well so all executables end up in the same build directory.  And make it the default startup project, so F5 gets it all going without having to search for anything or write any extra code.

Comment: @HansPassant C is part of the same solution. So the executable with the tests would be in the same folder as the generated DLLs?

Comment: You could in your settings for each project select a common folder to put the binaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you could try to use the function GetModuleFileNameA to get the path to DLL.

```
DWORD GetModuleFileNameA(
  HMODULE hModule,
  LPSTR   lpFilename,
  DWORD   nSize
);
```

You could refer to the example:

```
char szPath[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileNameA(dllhandle, szPath, MAX_PATH);
```